# Core Data Insert one to many with multiples relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

[image]
Good afternoon!

I am using the core date to save the following entity.

**Training Program > Activities > Series**

When saving the activities within the program, I am using the method.

```
let programTranningDB = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ProgramTranningDB", into: self.getContext())
(programTranningDB as! ProgramTranningDB).addToActivities(activities)
do{
            try self.getContext().save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

How can I add series into activities?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model looks a little like this:

[image]

- A TrainingProgram can have *many* activities.
- An Activity can have *many* series.

You will add an instance of **Series** to an **Activity** in the same way as you add the **Activity** to a **TrainingProgram**.

You can use the auto-generated method on **Activity** of `addToSeries(_:)`

I usually keep all my data domain logic contained in a class to aid testing and separation of concerns.

```
class DomainLogic {

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context
    }

    func addNewProgram(named: String) -> TrainingProgram  {
        guard let program = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "TrainingProgram", into: context) as? TrainingProgram else {
            preconditionFailure("TrainingProgram should be created here")
        }
        program.name = named
        return program
    }

    func addNewActivityToProgram(_ program: TrainingProgram) -> Activity {
        guard let activity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Activity", into: context) as? Activity else {
            preconditionFailure("Activity should be created here")
        }
        program.addToActivities(activity)
        return activity
    }

    func addNewSeriesToActivity(activity: Activity) -> Series {
        guard let series = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Series", into: context) as? Series else {
            preconditionFailure("Series should be created here")
        }
        activity.addToSeries(series)
        return series
    }
}
```

Which leads to a simple sequence to create a new **Series** and add it down the chain.

```
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    func createSeries() -> Series {
        let logic = DomainLogic(context: context)
        let program = logic.addNewProgram(named: "Fatima's Program")
        let activity = logic.addNewActivityToProgram(program)
        let series = logic.addNewSeriesToActivity(activity: activity)
        return series
    }
```

You'll also need logic to recover existing **TrainingProgram** objects from the database.